# Different IP and Subnets with different Gateways on Single NIC -Debian

Tags: networking, debian

I have a Debian server with only 1 Network Interface **eno1**. I have a router present which provides internet to my LAN and available at **192.168.1.1**. I need to add a second network to my VOIP provider with **WAN IP 100.75.171.131** and subnet **255.255.255.240** with VOIP gateway as **100.75.171.127**.

Hence I need to create two different IP's with different subnets and connecting to 2 different gateways on a single Interface on my Debian server.

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo eno1
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1:0
#1(Internet)
allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.168.1.111
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
post-up route add default gw 192.168.1.1 metric 1
pre-down route del default gw 192.168.1.1

#2(VOIP)
iface eno1:0 inet static
address 100.75.171.131
netmask 255.255.255.240
network 100.75.171.0
post-up route add default gw 100.75.171.127 metric 2
pre-down route del default gw 100.75.171.127
```

is this the correct way to add multiple IP's to a single interface and with static routes so that it works properly. Requesting support from Networking Experts.

Comment: I think not.  "route add default" is probably the same as "route add 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0" or "route add 0.0.0.0/0".  (I say "probably" there because the exact syntax may vary between operating systems, and I'm not sure of Debian offhand.)  The "default" route is what you'll use for the Internet if you don't have something more specific. 
 However, you probably only want to send VPN traffic, so you want a narrower route.  Your #2(VOIP) route might be something more like "route add 100.75.160.0 netmask 255.255.255.240".

Comment: Usually it's the difference between iproute2 `ip route` and the legacy `route` tool that trips people up (e.g. the former uses 'via' and the latter uses 'gw'). Each of the two tools has the same syntax on every distro, though.

Comment: Anyway – what are the conditions for using one gateway vs another? Does your VoIP program only need to reach some specific destinations via the new gateway (i.e. routes based on destination)? Or does it expect to be able to _bind_ to 100.75.171.131 as its local address and then reach some arbitrary, unknown destinations (i.e. policy routing)?

Comment: It should bind to 100.75.171.131 as its local address